# Bootstrap data in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, statistics-bootstrap

I have data similar to this:

`x = 0:0.1:10;
y = exppdf(x,2);
plot(x,y, 'o')`

and then I want to have some resampled data close to them, but when I use the command below , the resampled data are really far from the original one!

`[resampling, bootsam]=bootstrp(100, 'corr', x,y);
plot(x,y(bootsam(:,100)), 'r*')`

Could you please help me? I guess I need to change option 'corr' in the bootstrp command.

Comment: Please define what you want to do in terms of "resampling".  i.e. give some sample input and output values for x and y.  What you are currently plotting after `bootstrp` is your original x against randomly selected values out of y - it will never be close to the original.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are trying to do:

```
plot(x, sort(y(bootsam(:,100)), 'descend'), 'r*')
```

or maybe this:

```
plot(x(bootsam(:,100)),y(bootsam(:,100)), 'r*')
```

I guess it depends on what x is for you.